# How to make nested select statement in postgis

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I have this query as shown in the fiddle file. I would like to add a select statment inside a select statement in the code. The select statement I would like to add is:

```
SELECT array_agg(ST_X(geom)),array_agg(ST_Y(geom))
FROM ST_DumpPoints('POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))');
```

I would like to add it after `XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone`,
how can this be achieved?

**fiddle file**:

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=190e18c8f41deee45e53e2f5d8d846ab
```

Comment: the alias `bufferedZoneGeometryAsText` does not exist in your query and your fiddle does not execute. Could you fix that?

Comment: @JimJones question modified

Comment: Where does the column `geom` come from? The outer query does not have this column

Comment: geom??where is that?

Comment: @JimJones geom?where is that?

Comment: In your example you dump points out of a geometry. Which geometry you mean in your query?

Comment: @JimJones the geometry of the intersection

Comment: Using which column you want to aggreate (array_agg) your array? by gid?

Comment: is this what you want? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c5f9f1b4a55a7428ed25debf71ba470

Comment: does the last fiddle work?

Comment: @JimJones i did not test it yet

Comment: would you please tell me why in the fiddle with WITH clause the :WITH data AS (   is preceded with , (
??

Comment: because it became a subquery. it is in the where clause of a outer query

Comment: @JimJones would you mind to have a chat session i have a problem and i need your recommendation please

Comment: If the answer does not work for you, say so. If you have a problem, ask a question. If the problem isn't related to the original post, ask another question :) the chat is supposed to be an exception for highly complex issues or maybe just a courtesy, not a hot line for troubleshooting ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `array_agg` you need to `group by` something, otherwise you'll aggregate your whole table. Considering you want to group the column `XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone` by `gid`

In your case it would be something like

```
SELECT 
  gid,-- mind that it is also in the group by clause.
  array_agg(ST_X(XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone)),
  array_agg(ST_Y(XOfLowerLeftOfGridCellIntersectingWithBufferedZone))
FROM t
GROUP BY gid
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c5f9f1b4a55a7428ed25debf71ba470)

**Side note**: I strongly suggest you go go back to the drawing board. Your query is large and full of redundant statements, which is a side effect of simply combining distinct queries without proper refactoring. It is fine if it's just an exercise on what PostGIS is capable of, but it is hardly the best approach. Take a look at CTE, subqueries, aggreate functions, windown functions and try to understand how they work. It might seem a lot but it will pay off in the long run.